# paper-dropdown-menu's label not updating when menu items are added dynamically

Tags: drop-down-menu, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

When paper-dropdown-menu items are dynamically added its label will not update,
but its selected value is changing ,which is not displaying in label

It's illustrated in PLUNKER : https://plnkr.co/edit/jy7WxttkB1mN7z0uHuVJ?p=preview

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Patient">
<paper-menu class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedPatient}}" attr-for-selected="value">
  <template is="dom-repeat" id="patientMenu"  items="[[patientsList]]">
    <paper-item class="patient-names" value="[[item.id]]">[[item.id]][[item.name]]</paper-item>
  </template>
</paper-menu>
```

```
 <paper-button  on-tap="_fun" raised>change Array list</paper-button>

<div style="color:blue;">selected patient id--->[[selectedPatient]]</div>
```

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-test',
  properties: {
      patientsList:{
        type:Array
      }
  },

  ready:function() {
    this.patientsList =[
                              {id:0,name:"aaa"},
                              {id:1,name:"bbb"},
                              {id:2,name:"ccc"},
                              {id:3,name:"ddd"},
                              {id:4,name:"eee"}
                     ];
    this.selectedPatient = 0;
  },

    _fun:function(){
      this.selectedPatient = null;
              this.patientsList = [
                              {id:100,name:"xxx"},
                              {id:101,name:"yyy"},
                              {id:102,name:"qqq"},
                              {id:103,name:"mmm"},
                              {id:4,name:"eee"}
                     ];
    this.selectedPatient = 100;


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I trying your plunker, especially the "it work the second time" part, make think that the issue can be that the `dom-repeat` hadn't time to updates the items when the

```
this.selectedPatient = 100;
```

is executed.

I tried to change it to a

```
this.async(function(){
  this.set('selectedPatient',100)
}.bind(this));
```

to make sure the `selectedPatient` is set only after the `dom-repeat` is updated, and it seems to do the trick.